# Moving previous image in ScrollView using button click

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

When I press previous button it does not take any effect. Next Button is working properly but previous button do not show previous image. I am using `scroll view` to load images:

```
- (IBAction)next{
    int arraycount = [appDelegate.articles count];
    for (int nextIndex = [pageControl currentPage]; nextIndex < arraycount; nextIndex++) {  
        if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x <= self.scrollView.frame.size.width ) {
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x +     self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
            [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
            pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction)previousButtonAction
{
    int arraycount = [appDelegate.articles count];
    NSLog(@" arraycount : %d", arraycount);
    NSLog(@" [pageControl currentPage] : %d", [pageControl currentPage]);
    for (int nextIndex = [pageControl currentPage]; nextIndex>arraycount; nextIndex--) {
        if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x >= self.scrollView.frame.size.width ) {
            CGRect frame;
            frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x + self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
            frame.origin.y = 0;
            frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
            [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
            pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I now think I would approach this differently. I would check the current offset before re-assigning it.

untested code:

```
- (IBAction)next{
    if ( self.scrollView.contentOffset.x <= self.scrollView.frame.size.width ) {
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.contentOffset.x + self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
        [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
        pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: from where you will next index value from loop you have not mentioned here

Comment: Its working perfect thanks if i want for previous then may use only decrement sign

Answer (score 0):

I would disable the "next" button when the user gets to the third image. If you prefer to return to the first image when the user presses "next" in the third image, then you must add an additional else after your if to indicate that case:

```
- (IBAction)next{
int arraycount = [appDelegate.articles count];
for (int nextIndex = [pageControl currentPage]; nextIndex < arraycount; nextIndex++) {      
     if (nextIndex < arraycount) {
         CGRect frame;
         frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * nextIndex;
         frame.origin.y = 0;
         frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
         [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
          pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
      }
      // If the user clicks on next in the last item, return to the first
      else {
         CGRect frame;
         frame.origin.x = 0;
         frame.origin.y = 0;
         frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
         [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
          pageControlBeingUsed = YES;
      }
  }
```

}

Comment: in else statement i am disabling button but again it is coming back to second image

Answer (score 0):

arraycount = 3

[pageControl currentPage] is zero indexed so when you are on page 3 it equals 2.

so the start of your for loop nextIndex equals 2 which is less than arrayCount so it gets into your loop.

change it to:

```
for (int nextIndex = [pageControl currentPage]; nextIndex < (arraycount-1); nextIndex++) {
```

okay what does this output:

```
- (IBAction)next{
    int arraycount = [appDelegate.articles count];
NSLog(@" arraycount : %d", arraycount);
NSLog(@" [pageControl currentPage] : %d", [pageControl currentPage]);
    for (int nextIndex = [pageControl currentPage]; nextIndex < (arraycount-1); nextIndex++) {
NSLog(@" nextIndex : %d", nextIndex);
         CGRect frame;
         frame.origin.x = self.scrollView.frame.size.width * nextIndex;
         frame.origin.y = 0;
         frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
         [self.scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
          pageControlBeingUsed = YES;

      }
}
```

Comment: its not working as you are saying problem is that in my code after reaching 3 image again goes to second when click ob button

Comment: Set a breakpoint and step through the code to see why it is getting into the for loop. or try nslogs like my code above.

Comment: it is giving arraycount 3 and nextIndex value 1 only

Comment: Why are you starting nextIndex at [pageControl currentPage] ? You're not as far as I can see incrementing the pageControl page anywhere?

Comment: where do you think you are keeping track of which image you are showing? e.g.

Comment: i have edited where i load image but when i scroll with finger they are working fine but when click on button the do problem as mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Fo me it is working in swift 3.

```
 func prevAction (sender:UIButton)
{
    print("self.scView.contentOffset.x ..\(self.scView.contentOffset.x)")
    if ( self.scView.contentOffset.x <= self.scView.contentSize.width )
    {
        var frame = CGRect()

        frame.origin.x = self.scView.contentOffset.x - 80;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        frame.size = self.scView.frame.size;

        self.scView .scrollRectToVisible(frame, animated: true)

    }


}
```

Thanks to @ader.